# Why parent overide version of child dependency

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have spring boot app:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

which support hazelcast 3.*

I want to use  hazelcast 4.* so I create common jar project with some of common feature and add it to my project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cz.my</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-hazelcast-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

this dependency use hazelcast 4.* when I check dependency I can see version 3 is used:

```
[INFO] +- cz.my:my-hazelcast-common:jar:2.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:3.12.8:compile
```

how I can keep using version from dependency and not from parent ?

Answer (score 0):

These versions are set in the `spring-boot-dependencies` which is a parent of your parent.

You need to override the properties

```xml
<hazelcast.version>3.12.8</hazelcast.version>
<hazelcast-hibernate5.version>1.3.2</hazelcast-hibernate5.version>
```

and maybe some more depending on what you want to do.

You cannot just ignore the values and use the one from your dependency. You need to override this explicitly.